# Problems with gluint and glint

Tags: opengl

When I want to use gluint and glint, I'm getting the following errors,

```
gluint was not declared in this scope
glint was not declared in this scope
```

Am I missing a library that I'm already supposed to have? Everything else requiring GLFW and GLEW in the program is working fine and when I replace gluint and glint with unsigned int and int then the program runs.

Doesn't work the way it's supposed to but it still runs. I'll figure that out when I get to it, I assume it's something to do with my vertex and fragment shader code being crap.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using C or C++, since you didn't say which.

There are no `glint` and `gluint` definitions in OpenGL. There *are* `GLint` and `GLuint` however. C/C++ are case-sensitive languages, after all.

Comment: I am actually using GLint and GLuint, sorry about that (it was 5am). And yes, I'm using C++.

Comment: @snarehanger: How are we supposed to help you when you 1) misrepresent your problem by not showing the *exact* error messages 2) don't include vital information like what language you're programming in and 3) don't show us the actual source code that's having a problem? You need to edit your question and provide useful information that people can use to answer your question, rather than just guessing at answers.